# How to clone project from gitlab with sourcetree by the url with ip address

Tags: git, clone, atlassian-sourcetree, git-clone

I m mobile dev and I got user name, password and the git url to clone the project:

As you see below the url contains ip address with port which makes me think the project is stored on the customers server.

I have already unsuccessfully tried to login with provided username and password to the gitlab.

```
git url http://_ip_adress_with_port_here_/users/sign_in
```

How to clone such url by the source tree???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't clone this URL, this is for user login.

You need repository URL to be cloned.

Some like this:

```
http://<ip_adress>:<port>/<repository_name>.git
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, socketz! And where could I enter this url to sign in? The url is not visible on the web

Comment: Probably you don't have access to repositories. Check the URL you had post, login and if not appear in your GitLab repositories, need request access to a GitLab admin.